# Calculation of overtime though if/else statement

Tags: c#, webforms

A parking garage charges $5.00 to park for up to three hours. The garage charges an additional $ 1.50 per hour for each hour or part thereof in excess of three hours. The maximum charge for any given 24 hour period is $ 18.00. Assume that no car parks for longer than 24 hours at a time.

I am in the process of creating an if statement to follow these specific rules. The if statements that I have tried so far have not produced the result I am looking for. What if statement would cover these rules?

Here is my .aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function multiply() {
    var hoursParked = document.getElementById('hP').value;
    var price = 5.00;
    var totalCost = document.getElementById('total');
    var totalPayment = (hoursParked * price);
    if (hours < 3) {
        sum = price * hours;
        return sum;}
    else {
        sum = ((hours - 3) * 0.5 * price) + (price * hours);
        return sum; }
    totalCost.value = sum; }
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<form id="myForm" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" placeholder="Hours parked?" min="1" Max="24"></asp:TextBox><br /><br /> 
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Calculate" OnClick="Button1_Click" Width="69px" Height="26px" /><br /><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" placeholder="Total Cost" readonly>    </asp:TextBox>
</form> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally here is where I am attempting to create my if/else statement.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Project2
{
public partial class Part2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int hours = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
        //double total = hours * 5; hours * 5 would apply until the user is parked for more than 3 hours, from there it would change to an additional 1.50
        //if/else statement should go here defining what happens after 3 hours have passed, and what happens when someone parks for 24 hours.
        TextBox2.Text = total.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your statement currently boils down to `if (something) { return; } else { return } do stuff` which probably isn't what you intended... (you know what `return` does right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, brute force it:

```
double GetTotal(int hours) {
   // A parking garage charges $5.00 to park for up to three hours. 
   if (hours <= 3) return 5.0;

   // The garage charges an additional $ 1.50 per hour for each hour or part thereof in excess of three hours. 
   double total = 5;
   total += (hours - 3) * 1.5;

   // The maximum charge for any given 24 hour period is $18.00. 
   if (total > 18) total = 18;

   // Assume that no car parks for longer than 24 hours at a time.
   if (hours > 24) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("hours");

   return total;
}
```

You can always clean it up later, if it's worth it - in this case, I'd note that the minimum charge is $5 and the maximum charge is $18 and there's no other special cases:

```
double GetTotal(int hours) {
   if (hours > 24) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("hours");

   double total = 5.0 + (hours - 3) * 1.5;
   if (total < 5) return 5;
   if (total > 18) return 18;
   return total;
}
```

Oh, and I wouldn't use double for money (use decimal instead).

Answer (score 2):

Dont do the calculation in javascript clientside.

Send the time the user wishes to park for to the server.

Then

```
float MinCharge = 5.0;
if (HoursToPark > 3) {
    MinCharge += (HoursToPark-3) * 1.5;
} 
if (MinCharge > 18.0) {
    MinCharge = 18.0;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest a more sane use of variable names.  Make `MinCharge` a `const` and call the result variable something like `finalPrice` or some such.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if (hours < 3) 
{
    sum = 5;
}
else
{
    sum = 5 + (hours - 3) * 1.50;
}

if (sum > 18)
{
    sum = 18;
}
```

Comment: This is very efficient way to solve this problem. Thanks mate.

Comment: Also see Vans' comment about not doing this client side.  Any calculation done in the browser can be modified by an attacker.